# Which champion is best for solo-ing baron at 15 minute mark? If that's not possible then which two champions together will be able to?

Tags: league-of-legends

IT would be great to know so that people can do baron secretly therefore having an advantage or catching up?

Comment: It's nearly *impossible* for AD champions because of [Baron's Voracious Corrosion debuff](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Baron_Nashor#Abilities), which *halves your current AD*. The only champion that can probably do it at the 15 minute mark is Fiddlesticks, as any other champion needs far more itemization than you can get at 15 minutes. Best do a sneaky Baron with 2 members of your team, and later in the game when you can clear it quickly so you're not interrupted.

Comment: The debuff is going to be changed to reduce physical and magical damage done to Baron Nashor [source](http://www.newsoflegends.com/index.php/pbe-updates-explained-morello-on-jannaaura-items-xelnath-examines-rengar-future-caitlyn-and-the-new-rotation-and-sale-11121/#balance). Now you will also have a hard time soloing it with Fiddlesticks :P

Answer (score 6):

[The Baron Nashor is hard to kill.](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Baron_Nashor)

**Statistics**

```
 Health  8852 + 125 every 1 min
```

It is **NEVER** worth it to "Solo" Baron (Unless you are full gear and kill him in a couple of seconds). Because:

1. You waste lots of time doing it alone
2. You can be easily ganked/killed
3. After a small push you can call 2 or 3 teammates and do it quickly, so why do it alone? It's a team type game after all, right ?!
4. Take a look at this link: [When should I Baron?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/56739/12936)

---

> But Michel, I really want to give it a try, so which champion is good
>   for it?

Basically Attack Damage based Champions:

- Tryndamere
- Vayne
- Kog'maw

Those 3 are the best for the service.

- Tryndamere has a huge amount of damage and his ult can keep him alive for extra damage.
- Vayne does True damage, and with enough attack speed and damage you will not have any trouble at all
- Kog'maw has good skill rotation, and he match really well with Madred blood razor.

Others good champions are:

- Gangplank
- Shaco
- Heimidinger
- Olaf

---

**NOTES:** At 15min you can do Baron between 15 and 30 seconds with 3 level 12 without much trouble, or even 2 if you two are fed as hell (bot style for the win). So go for it with a couple of friends and you will be fine. Care for wards (Oracle or pink ward here). Check out for the enemy invasion too.

Comment: Good answer, but I would add that Fiddlesticks is also a good choice if you're maxing drain when possible, blue buffed and heavily stacking AP.

Comment: Fiddle drain is not what it used to be. But, yes, here is a good pick for the task. But as a AP based I think that is not wise (you kind need a specific rune/mastery set for this). Also, you need the Blue buff (mandatory) and also some CD reduction gear or masteries or runes.

Answer (score 1):

Solo'ing Baron at 15 minutes is almost impossible unless ridiculously fed, in which case you probably don't need to catch up.

Duo'ing Baron however, is not unheard of.  CLG recently did so with Shen and Udyr's combined lifesteal/spellvamp of Vorpal Blade and Turtle Stance.  Basically you need champions that can either do huge damage to Baron or out-sustain/tank Baron's damage.

For damage: Kog'Maw, Karthus, Heimerdinger, Vayne, Cho'Gath

For sustain: Shen, Udyr, Olaf, Lee Sin

Wriggle's Lantern helps **immensely**.

Answer (score 1):

Warwick, with the blade of ruined king and the glacial shround for a bit armour, can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any champ that can solo baron at the 15min mark.

Perhaps one with a ton for lifesteal/attack speed (Tyrndamere) may be able to do it with a support champ rather early on.

Comment: It'd take at least until 20+ minutes, but best option would probably be Olaf imo.

Answer (score 0):

CLG just did this in the recent IPL4 finals, and if i'm not mistaken it was with Vayne and Udyr.

It was around 17 min i think though.

Comment: Link ? I Was looking at TSM and CLG and didn't found this .... http://ipl4.leagueoflegends.com/match/championship-tsm-vs-clg

Comment: I was actually a little off in the minute mark, it is around 22min. 57:07 in the video.

Answer (score 0):

Warwick is probably the obvious choice for sneaking early solo barons.  He has great sustain combined with reasonable damage.  His attack speed steroid also works very well with Wriggles (which you will definitely want for early barons).

With that being said, doing it solo at the 15 minute mark is optimistic at best unless you get ridiculously fed.  I'd always bring at least one other person if possible too since it just takes too long early. Something like Tiger Udyr with Wriggles would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I soloed baron as fiora, with my build about halfway done. Granted I was level eighteen... But it is possible to solo baron with fiora. I had about 1/4 health left, so probably not the best choice. I want to say fiddlesticks, just because he can also usually solo dragon at level 7. But he is very squishy, and baron has somewhat crowd control (knock upward) so he can cancel fid's drain. Baron also can't be feared, or at least not well. And the silence works best when it is in a group of enemies. So he might not be the right person for the job. I would pick someone who has low cooldowns, possibly riven or katarina. If you take someone who is mana reliant, they will more than likely run out of it, and be killed. That or go tanky ad. Those would all be okay, but that's my opinion, because I don't think the same way most people do.. Some people might think this comment is absolute garbage but it makes complete sense in my mind. But don't solo at fifteen minutes. It's not worth the possibility of unnecesary death
Soloing baron does have it's advantages, so I'm not 100% against it. 
For instance, it keeps the baron attempt under the radar, unless they have it warded, but buy an oracle just in case. One champion missing usually means jungling, whereas a whole team missing almost always signals baron attempt.
Also, with the large amount of time it takes to solo baron, the other team will probably assume that you are afk, and will push instead of baron.
Solo baron obviously doesn't take the whole team to do it, and if you solo, the rest of the team can push, or steal their jungle buffs, or gank. 
That alone gives it enough of an advantage to keep me interested in it. I never thought it was possible until I did it.

Answer (score -1):

its actually possible to solo baron with Dr. mundo at lvl 12. I have done it myself, so if you just get a little bit fed its actually possible.

Comment: Level 12 is optimistic for 15 minutes, wouldn't you say?

Answer (score -4):

You could accomplish this using Warwick. The build I used was:

- Any boots (Ninja Tabi, Mercury Treads, Boots of Mobility... anything works)
- Zephyr
- Wit's end
- Warmog's Armor
- Thornmail
- Bloodthirster (Either early or late)

Choose your pick.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade. It would be a lot better if you took the time to explain your answer more thoroughly - why and how does it work? Advantages/disadvantages? etc.

Comment: Also... that's more than 10,000 in items, you're not going to have that at 15 minutes.